# Can you break a rope you are tied up with instead of making an escape check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Rope states

> **Hempen** The DC to escape hemp rope bonds is equal to 20 + the CMB of the creature that tied the bonds. Ropes do not need to make a check every round to maintain the pin. If the DC to escape is higher than 20 + the tying creatures CMB, the tied up creature cannot escape from the bonds, even with a natural 20 on the check. This rope has 2 hit points and can be burst with a DC 23 Strength check.

However, I can't find anywhere if it is possible to make a break check when you are tied up with a rope or not. Escape could refer to making a check to escape, lathe than break, so this doesn't seem a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the wording of the description it seems clear to me that you can burst the rope while tied up.

The important distinction to make is between escaping the bonds and bursting them. You escape the bonds by passing the DC 20 + CMB of tying creature check. You burst the rope (and thereby are untied) by passing the DC 23 Strength Check.